# Express ( node.js ) - TypeError: Cannot read properties of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I use Express ( node.js ) and MongoDB. When I try to view or update user profile I get an error

```
middleware token check worked
    getProfileFields:::::::::::::>>>>e:  TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'minAge')
    at module.getProfileFields (C:\localhost\website\app\controllers\api\profile.js:34:22)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

it seems problem with this part of code

```
module.getProfileFields = async (req, res) => {
        var successMessage = { status: 'success', message:"", data:{}};
        var failedMessage = { status: 'fail', message:"", data:{}};
        try {
            var profileFields = await model.ProfileFields.find({isDeleted:false},{slug:1, options:1,type: 1});
            var obj = {
                ...
                educationLevel: [],
                hobbies: [],
                whatYouSay: [],
                minAge: settings.minAge ? settings.minAge : 0,
                maxAge: settings.maxAge ? settings.maxAge : 0,
                religion: []                
            };
            

            }

            successMessage.message = "Successfully loaded profile reference";
            successMessage.data = obj;
            res.send(successMessage);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('getProfileFields:::::::::::::>>>>e: ',e);
            failedMessage.message = "Something went wrong";
            res.send(failedMessage);
        }
    }
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: settings is empty

Comment: `settings` is `undefined`... (If that's an expected value under some conditions, you can use `settings?.minAge`)

Comment: Settings may be undefined

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'minAge')` means that the line where you first access `minAge` is having `settings` be null: `minAge: settings.minAge ? settings.minAge : 0,`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same error "Cannot read properties of null (reading "X")" when trying to read and update mongoDB using express. My mistake was that in the `req.body`, one of the attributes was the wrong type, let's say I was supposed to send a number but I was sending a string.

```json
{
  orderNumber: "1234"
}
```

Instead of:

```json
{
  orderNumber: 1234
}
```

I recommend you to check your request to confirm what you are actually sending.

Answer (score 0):

Settings are empty, maybe they are not exported correctly. Check your settings file.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're not using the find API call for MongoDB properly,
find usually takes up a filter object and an object of properties as a second argument.
Check the syntax required for find(){} function and probably you'll get through with it.

Hope it helps.
Happy coding!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).